# How should I store database connection information for my unit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a series of PHPUnit tests that will need to connect to a database. I would like to avoid hardcoding a specific database/username/password into each unit test. How can they share this information?

Right now I am setting these as key/value pairs in the $GLOBALS array in my PHPUnit bootstrap file. Should they be somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put them in the %ENV

```
export DB_PASS=foo
export DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
export DB_USER=bar
```

or you can have a config file outside of your repository.

Answer (score 2):

$GLOBALS is quite dirty. You could use constants or derive the unit tests from a class that has the connection data as properties.